# Huawei Ascend G300 (U6615) not using Three network

Tags: 3g

I bought an ex-Vodaphone Huawei G300, and was happy to find that it was unlocked - I put in my Giffgaff SIM, and immediately had phone and internet access.

However, I really want to use the phone on Three, but although calls and texts can be made and received, I can get no internet.

I tapped 'New APN', and set it up in accordance with 3, but even though I saved it after inputting their settings, the APN screen remained blank, and no connection could be obtained.

The settings entered were:

Name – 3 Internet

APN - three.co.uk

Proxy, Port, Username, Password & Server - blank

MMSC -  http://mms.um.three.co.uk:10021/mmsc

MMS PROXY -  mms.three.co.uk

MMS Port - 8799

MCC - 234

MNC - 15

Authentication type - None

APN type left blank

Is there something I don't know??

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MCC/MNC table for UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code#United_Kingdom_-_GB), your MNC code should be 20, not 15. Also [this page](http://wiki.melberi.com/2013/05/three-mobile-uk-apn-settings-for.html) suggests that you need to enter `default,supl,mms` (without spaces after commas) in the “APN Type” field.

If this still won't work, try omitting all MMS-related settings (MMSC, MMS Proxy, MMS Port) and entering `default,supl` in the “APN Type” field, then, if you get your 3G Internet connection working this way, add another APN just for MMS with all settings and `mms` in the “APN Type” field.

Comment: Sergey,Many thanks - you hit the spot first time: it was the default,supl,mms entry that made the difference. Now getting three internet fine. Thanks again